# How to store token in LocalStorage in react library

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react, I have written everything code in the backend. Now if I log in now token is coming into the network. Now my problem is how to store that token in LocalStorage and where I have to store it, please tell me what to do and how to do.

If you have any doubts, please put a comment

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know how to store token in local storage, but I have seen something like this in stack overflow  -> localStorage.setItem('myData', data);  is this correct way to try.

Comment: Do not comment comments asking for clarification or additional information: edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it as a client-side cookie or in a **localStorage** or **sessionStorage**. There are pros and cons in each option.  you should have access to the localStorage instance which has setter and getter to store and retrieve data from the local storage.

```js
// setter
localStorage.setItem('token', data);
// getter
localStorage.getItem('token');
// remove
localStorage.removeItem('token');
// remove all
localStorage.clear();
```

> You can also check this snippet for reference.  https://codesandbox.io/embed/winter-bird-uirri?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, in localStorage.setItem('token',data)  here in token I will put token but what I have to write in data?

Comment: data should be the token value, as you already mentioned which is coming from network request.

Comment: then what have to put in token?

Comment: I have one more question where I have to store that token in the constructor or I have to store it in a function or I have store it in a variable please tell me how to store in react?

Comment: its just a name, you can write anything you want to name your token-data, so you can retrieve them by that name.

Comment: @Hare this might be helpful
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-bird-uirri